# Skydrive direct links

Tags: blog, onedrive

I'm using Skydrive to host files for my blog, such as zip files of source code. I'm trying to provide direct links that users on my blog can click to immediately download the file in question, without being confronted with a Skydrive page filled with all the files related to all posts on my blog.

Is there a way to do this? I've tried getting a link to the file, shortening it et cetera, but visiting this link always shows the Skydrive page. Here is [an example](http://sdrv.ms/13mwN2v).

At this point I can only assume Skydrive is doing this on purpose and am also wondering whether there's another provider I can switch to that will yield a better user experience.

Answer (score 5):

you can just generate share link via UI (for example: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=CA1656805C59C6C9!174&authkey=!ABYGECM1-9fSPG8), then replace "redir" for "download" (like this: https://skydrive.live.com/download?resid=CA1656805C59C6C9!174&authkey=!ABYGECM1-9fSPG8) and this will be direct download link.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this explanation](http://pastebin.com/iZhJXpeV)

> You can't get exact direct link of this demo.zip , but the direct link
>   for the photos, videos, etc. you can.
>
> Example:
>
> As we can see the complete link of your shorten link (
>   http://sdrv.ms/13mwN2v ) is
>   https://skydrive.live.com/cid=328ba01b2a22de20&id=328BA01B2A22DE20%21219&authkey=!APtFM-r5ezVjuoc
>   . This link is directed to the zip file "demo" .
>
> Use this to find your direct link for this zip file:
>
> http://storage.live.com/items/YOUR_CID_AND_YOUR_ID?filename=NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE
>
> Change YOUR_CID_AND_YOUR_ID with your real cid with your id which is
>   328ba01b2a22de20%21219 and change NAME_OF_YOUR_FILE with the real name
>   of your file ( in this case **demo** ) ( you can put behind demo .zip
>   , or no needed )
>
> So your link would be:
>
> http://storage.live.com/items/328ba01b2a22de20%21219?filename=demo.zip
>
> In this case, just like I told above, the direct link for downloading
>   would appear without extension and with some strange name , which your
>   users would need to rename into demo.zip.
>
> If you've had photo, video, any other file ( just not with an
>   extension .zip or .rar ) , they would get during downloading, the file
>   also with some strange name, but with the correct extension.
>
> Example:
>
> Your second above file is called also demo, but it is the photo. And
>   the link for this photos is - https://skydrive.live.com/
>   cid=328BA01B2A22DE20&id=328BA01B2A22DE20%21218&authkey=%21APtFM-r5ezVjuoc
>
> The same instruction is:
>
> http://storage.live.com/items/328ba01b2a22de20%21218?filename=demo.jpg
>
> And in this case, you'll get another direct link:
>
> http://public.sn2.livefilestore.com/y2pH-j1knnF0V7NKzvgruin8-MevGUhi0vmTVUGQ-E8m62ct5NAcQVMgSCpbr3Mb9tRrRdYFWyE2t6nd0WhV_Fp9lIkOIXUSXocmNRwUHRWvXU?filename=demo.jpg